# Confused using Ajax call and Drupal 7 Form

Tags: 7, ajax

I need to query a database with two parameters, which means more than one form variable needs to be passed to the server -(select where field =).  Looking at all the examples of the Drupal 7 ajax api, I've only seen where one variable is passed.

Using jquery it seems far simpler where as now I'm not sure how to parse and sanitize the post variables that are passed to the callback function.  All the examples I've seen have the callback simply returning the form.  I would think the query logic goes here along with a drupal function to return the json.

In addition the page I have is a generated table,  In this table, one of the columns is an input text field.  I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but I've directly added an input text field in the array that's rendered from the result set.  That text field is editable, and if a new value is input
I want to be able to save that as a new value for the same rowid.  Therefore two variables need to be sent.

Any direction much appreciated.